# Random object transform in loop (Animation Nodes)

Tags: animation-nodes

how can I use AN to transform bunch of objects from one position to another in random order? Right now it looks like this:
[image]

So all fragments moves at the same time.

Greetings!

Answer (score 2):

First step would be to shuffle your list of objects before passing it to the routine.
Second, you can use the index of the object as a delay for your start of the animation. If 1 frame is too short, you can use a multiplier to create more offset in the animation.

Here is the updated node tree with the added nodes.

[image]

And here is the result of the objects moving from point A to B.

[image]

Comment: btw: you might want to disable the X and Z location checkboxes in the Object Transforms Output node. (getting and setting the location of the same object should be done with care, otherwise you may run into some recursion and the objects move away)